# How to get PID of perl daemon in init script?

Tags: linux, perl, daemon

I have the following perl script:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use Proc::Daemon;

Proc::Daemon::Init;

my $continue = 1;
$SIG{TERM} = sub { $continue = 0 };

while ($continue) {
        # stuff
}
```

I have the following in my init script:

```
DAEMON='/path/to/perl/script.pl'
start() {
    PID=`$DAEMON > /dev/null 2>&1 & echo $!`
    echo $PID > /var/run/mem-monitor.pid
}
```

The problem is, this returns the wrong PID! This returns the PID of the parent process which is started when the daemon is run, but that process is immediately killed off. I need to get the PID of the child process!

Comment: See documentation for [`Proc::Daemon`](https://metacpan.org/pod/Proc::Daemon). There is an option called `pid_file`. The PID will be written to this file.

Comment: Yes, I know I can use this option in Perl. However, I would like to keep functionality like that (creating, deleting PID file) inside the init script, rather than having 1/2 done in perl and 1/2 done in the init script.

Comment: You could try pass the filename from shell script to the Perl script on the command line, e.g. `$DAEMON $pid_file > /dev/null 2>&1 ....` Then the Perl script could use this file name `$pid_file` to create the pid file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you to the suggestions from zdim and Hakon. They are certainly workable, and got me on the right track, but ultimately I went a different route. Rather than relying on `$!`, I used `ps` and `awk` to get the PID, as follows:

```
DAEMON='/path/to/perl/script.pl'

start() {
    $DAEMON > /dev/null 2>&1
    PID=`ps aux | grep -v 'grep' | grep "$DAEMON" | awk '{print $2}'`
    echo $PID > /var/run/mem-monitor.pid
}
```

This works and satisfies my OCD! Note the double quotes around "$DAEMON" in `grep "$DAEMON"`.

Answer (score 2):

The [Proc::Daemon](http://search.cpan.org/~akreal/Proc-Daemon-0.23/lib/Proc/Daemon.pod) says

> Proc::Daemon does the following:
>   ...
>   9. The first child transfers the PID of the second child (daemon) to the parent. Additionally the PID of the daemon process can be written into a file if 'pid_file' is defined. Then the first child exits.

and then later, under `new ( %ARGS )`

> pid_file
>   Defines the path to a file (owned by the parent user) where the PID of the daemon process will be stored. Defaults to undef (= write no file).

Also look at `Init()` method description. This all implies that you may want to use `new` first.

The point is that it is the grand-child process that is the daemon. However, the childr passes the pid along and it is available to the parent. If `pid_file => $file_name` is set in the constructor (the daemon's) pid is written to that file.

---

A comment asks to not have shell script rely on a file written by another script.

I can see two ways to do that.

- Print the pid, returned by the `$daemon->Init()`, from the parent and pick it up in the shell. This is defeated by redirects in the question, but I don't know why they are needed. The parent and child exit right as all is set up, while the daemon is detached from everything.
- Shell script can start the Perl script with the desired log-file name as an argument, letting it write the daemon pid to that file by the above process. The file is still output by Perl, but what matters about it is decided by the shell script.

I'd like to include a statement from my comment below. I consider these superior to two other things that come to mind: picking the filename from a config-style file kept by the shell is more complicated, while parsing the process table may be unreliable.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. Would there be any way to access the grand-child's PID from shell? As I noted in my comments to the original question, I'd prefer to avoid creation of the PID file inside the Perl script. This does not feel kosher to me, as the init script will have to rely on a file created by the Perl script.

Comment: @Bintz  That is reasonable, I think. I added two other ways that I can see to the post.  Two others that I can think of don't look as good -- (1) Perl script picks up the file name to use from some sort of a config-file, kept by the shell.  That'd be more complicated and no better than passing the filename to the script, as in the answer (2) Shell finds the pid by tracking and analyzing the process table. That'd be horribly messy and unreliable. // I don't see yet other ways.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen this before and had to resort to using STDERR to send back the childs PID to the calling shell script.  I've always assumed it was due to the mentioned unreliability of exit codes - but details were not clear in the documentation.  Please try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Proc::Daemon;

if( my $pid = Proc::Daemon::Init() ) {
    print STDERR $pid;
    exit;
}

my $continue = 1;
$SIG{TERM} = sub { $continue = 0 };

while ($continue) {
    sleep(20);
    exit;
}
```

With a calling script like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
DAEMON='./script.pl'
start() {
    PID=$($DAEMON 2>&1 >/dev/null)
    echo $PID > ./mem-monitor.pid
}
start;
```

When the bash script is ran, it will capture the STDERR output (containing the correct PID), and store it in the file.  Any STDOUT the Perl script produces would be sent to /dev/null - though this is unlikely as the 1st level Perl script does (in this case) exit fairly early on.